# Return the lines if it matches the pattern in python

Tags: python

How can I print the line from a file if the pattern matches? But there is a caveat. The search should not consider any brackets in the line of the file. 
My search pattern is `CurrentPrincipalLegalEventAssociation`

Here is the content of file

```
941,agg.list,CurrentPrincipalMailingAddressStreetLine1,CompanyElementDefinition
c755ad,atom.list,CurrentPrincipal[LegalEventAssociation][Type][*],CompanyElementDefinition
8798c3,atom.list,CurrentPrincipal[MailingAddressStreetLine1][*],CompanyElementDefinition
2e43d1,atom.list,CurrentPrincipal[MailingAddressStreetLine2][*],CompanyElementDefinition
b3a13b,atom.list,CurrentPrincipal[MailingContinentName][*],CompanyElementDefinition
```

When I do the search it should return me the below line
`c755ad,atom.list,CurrentPrincipal[LegalEventAssociation][Type][*],CompanyElementDefinition`

Here the pattern does not have any brackets however, the line which I want has brackets in it. I am looking for a program which can ignore the brackets while matching the pattern.

I am new to python and all I know is to print a line if it matches a specific word but not of this sort.
Here is what I have tried but that did not work.

```
for line in file.splitlines():
    if "CurrentPrincipalLegalEventAssociation" in line:
        print line
```

Comment: Can you show what you've attempted and what exactly didn't work.

Comment: What have you written so far? You'll get better answers if you provide program (even a broken one) that other can fix.

Comment: How about removing the brackets from the line read and then look for the pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you need it to:

```
with open(filename) as myfile:
    for row in myfile:
        if 'CurrentPrincipalLegalEventAssociation' in row.replace('[', '').replace(']', ''):
            print(row)
```

This loops through the lines in the file, checks for your string after removing brackets, and returns a match if it finds one.